# make a list from sql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, foreach

I want to display a list from my ***SQL*** table based on the selected *columns*:

```
$list = $command -> select('*') -> from("{{list}}") -> queryRow();
```

**Code**:

```
<?php foreach($list["listname"] as $property => $k): ?>
<?php echo $property ?>
<?php echo $k ?>
```

It returns an **error** : 
*500 error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()*

If I change my code to this: 
`echo $list['listname'];` 

I only get the first row from the table.

Comment: check the query on the phpMyadmin console..and check how many records you get..

Comment: missing semicolon in echo

Comment: can you post the output of `var_dump($list)`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<?php
  if (is_array($list["listname"]))
  {
     foreach($list["listname"] as $property => $k)
     {
       echo $property."<br>";
       echo $k;
     }
   }
 ?>
```

I believe the query itself is returning one row...as its         queryRow();

```
     $list = $command -> select('*') -> from("{{list}}") -> queryRow();

     array &queryRow ( string $query , array $types = null , integer $fetchmode = MDB_FETCHMODE_DEFAULT , integer $rownum = null );
```

Description

Fetch the first row of data returned from a query. The function takes care of doing the query and freeing the results when finished.

[Reference](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.database.mdb.mdb-common.queryrow.php)

Comment: still display only the first row of the table

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to end the foreach with endforeach;

```
<?php foreach($list["listname"] as $property => $k): ?>
<?php echo $property ?>
<?php echo $k ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

You can also get more debug information by writing the following in the top of the php file:

```
ini_set('display_errors','On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: this code return 500 error "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Comment: if i close with "endforeach" i get "Array"

Comment: then either $property or $k is an Array. Try to use print_r($property) and print_r($k) instead.